# Can I copy a whole section from a book as an answer?

Tags: discussion

We have a question that has been unresolved for a few months. I have now found a section of a book (1-2 pages) which is excellently written and I wish to share as a possible answer. Am I allowed to just copy the whole section out and reference the source. I fear any attempt by me to paraphrase it will lose some crucial meaning.

Comment: Related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/9264/2451

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well... I can't imagine that a quote from a book (and a lengthy one at that) will really be an ideal answer. It's allowed to quote a passage from a book, sure, but at least add something to your answer. Like a summary or something in your own words.

Comment: A relevant quote from a good book may not be ideal, but it's quite likely in the top 75% of answers, in terms of quality... Of course a TL;DR at the start may be a useful guide to people who can't read a whole page of text.